# Is there a better way to compare values?

Tags: python

I'm creating a discord bot that auto creates users an MMR based on past games. When running a custom game of 10 people (or less) I need the bot to take the MMR value and compare it to all other players that have opted to join the game. This is how I am doing it... Please tell me if there is a better way.

```
  ## Evenly Seperate teams

  p1_place=10
  p2_place=10
  p3_place=10
  p4_place=10
  p5_place=10
  p6_place=10
  p7_place=10
  p8_place=10
  p9_place=10
  p10_place=10

  try:
    if Player1[1] > Player2[1]:
      p1_place=p1_place
    else:
      p1_place=p1_place-1
  except NameError:
    pass
  else:
    
    try:
      if Player1[1] > Player3[1]:
        p1_place=p1_place
      else:
        p1_place=p1_place-1
    except NameError:
      pass
    else:
      
      try:
        if Player1[1] > Player4[1]:
          p1_place=p1_place
        else:
          p1_place=p1_place-1
      except NameError:
        pass
      else:
        
        try:
          if Player1[1] > Player4[1]:
            p1_place=p1_place
          else:
            p1_place=p1_place-1
        except NameError:
          pass
        else:
          
          try:
            if Player1[1] > Player5[1]:
              p1_place=p1_place
            else:
              p1_place=p1_place-1
          except NameError:
            pass
          else:
            
            try:
              if Player1[1] > Player6[1]:
                p1_place=p1_place
              else:
                p1_place=p1_place-1
            except NameError:
              pass
            else:
              
              try:
                if Player1[1] > Player7[1]:
                  p1_place=p1_place
                else:
                  p1_place=p1_place-1
              except NameError:
                pass
              else:
                
                try:
                  if Player1[1] > Player8[1]:
                    p1_place=p1_place
                  else:
                    p1_place=p1_place-1
                except NameError:
                  pass
                else:
```

Comment: Can you provide sample input and desired output here? Also, use lists and iterate over those lists when you can instead of writing repetitive code.

Comment: @jarmod issue is Player# stores username and MMR . Suggestions on how to make it work as a list?

Comment: OK, so each 'player' is a list of 2 elements (username and MMR). What's the actual goal here? Is it simply to sort a list of players on MMR? On the player representation, a class/dataclass or named tuple would be preferable to a 2-element list, but you can probably come back to that later.

Comment: @jarmod Yeah, so the bot takes your username (which you provide when you create your profile) and goes to website that has MMRs for everyone's usernames. It scrapes that MMR from the website and stores it in an excel sheet along with you discord username and in game username. When you want to play a custom game, everyone playing types !join and when one user uses !start, the bot will take the users that have joined and divide them into two teams based on MMR as equally as possible.

Comment: @Julien if I only use one try block, I believe if any if statements provide a NameError (because there is less that 10 players) then none of the data comes back? Or am I wrong? I genuinely don't know

Comment: So, sort the list of players by MMR and then assign players 1,4,5,8,9 to team 1 and 2,3,6,7,10 to team 2 or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not 100% sure what you want here, but if it's to sort the list of players by MMS and then split into two teams, here's one simple idea:

```
players = [
    ["jim", 200],
    ["bob", 120],
    ["mike", 200],
    ["jane", 210],
    ["lacy", 90],
    ["stan", 250],
    ["luke", 150],
    ["bill", 100],
]

mms_sort = lambda p: -p[1]

players_by_mms = sorted(players, key=mms_sort)

# print(players_by_mms)

teams = [
    players_by_mms[0 : len(players_by_mms) : 2],
    players_by_mms[1 : len(players_by_mms) : 2],
]

print(teams)
```

Results are:

- team 0: [['stan', 250], ['jim', 200], ['luke', 150], ['bill', 100]]
- team 1: [['jane', 210], ['mike', 200], ['bob', 120], ['lacy', 90]]

You might want to modify the way players are assigned to teams to make it more equitable. The method here is  simply alternating from highest MMS down.

Comment: I was doing this at first, issue I have is what if there aren't 10 players it will prompt an error

Comment: Not sure I can help without more details on what the error you see is. The code I've added here shouldn't have the same issue anyway.